# Error During Apt-Mirror Unattended Install Of Ubuntu Server 12.04 Over Network Using PXE

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, pxe

I'm attempting to PXE boot and completely rebuild a new server with an "Ubuntu 12.04 Server" image over the network using apt-mirror but I get multiple errors mid-way through the installation. I am able to successfully rebuild the same server with a physical CDROM (created using the very same files from the "ubuntu-12.04.2-server-amd64.iso" image) without issue, yet I have issues building over the network as it provides the following error messages just after it partitions the discs and begins the last big file transfer. As a result, I have not been able to get a successful server PXE built using my business' internal network (using the external repository works).

Error 1:

> **!! Install the base system**
>
> **Debootstrap warning**
>
> **Warning: Couldn't download package eject (ver 2.1.5+deb1+cvs20081104-9 arc amd64)**

Error 2:

> **!! Install the base system**
>
> **Debootstrap warning**
>
> **Warning: Couldn't download package liblzma5 (ver 5.1.1alpha+20110809-3 arc amd64)**

Error 3:

> **!! Install the base system**
>
> **Debootstrap warning**
>
> **Warning: Couldn't download package libstdc++6 (ver 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 arc amd64)**

More similar errors appear but have been omitted for brevity...

Here's the last portion of the **/var/log/syslog**:

```
...
Jul 12 17:30:00 partman-lvm:   Logical volume "swap_1" successfully removed
Jul 12 17:30:00 udevd[24071]: inotify_add_watch(6, /dev/dm-1, 10) failed: No such file or directory
Jul 12 17:30:00 partman-lvm:   0 logical volume(s) in volume group "coolservername" now active
Jul 12 17:30:00 partman-lvm:   Volume group "coolservername" successfully removed
Jul 12 17:30:00 partman-lvm:   Labels on physical volume "/dev/sda3" successfully wiped
Jul 12 17:30:02 partman-lvm:   Physical volume "/dev/sda3" successfully created
Jul 12 17:30:02 partman-lvm:   Volume group "coolservername" successfully created
Jul 12 17:30:02 partman-lvm:   Logical volume "root" created
Jul 12 17:30:02 partman-lvm:   Logical volume "swap_1" created
Jul 12 17:30:06 kernel: [  184.508873] Adding 16695292k swap on /dev/mapper/coolservername-swap_1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16695292k
Jul 12 17:30:07 partman: mke2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
Jul 12 17:30:21 kernel: [  199.286079] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Jul 12 17:30:22 apt-install: Queueing package e2fsprogs for later installation
Jul 12 17:30:22 main-menu[514]: (process:25003): /var/lib/partman/devices/=dev=sda
Jul 12 17:30:23 main-menu[514]: DEBUG: resolver (libnewt0.52): package doesn't exist (ignored)
Jul 12 17:30:23 main-menu[514]: DEBUG: resolver (ext2-modules): package doesn't exist (ignored)
Jul 12 17:30:23 main-menu[514]: INFO: Menu item 'bootstrap-base' selected
Jul 12 17:30:23 debconf-copydb: Cannot open question file /target/var/cache/debconf/config.dat: No such file or directory
Jul 12 17:30:23 debconf-copydb: Cannot open template file /target/var/cache/debconf/templates.dat: No such file or directory
Jul 12 17:30:23 base-installer: chroot: can't execute 'debconf-set-selections': No such file or directory
Jul 12 17:30:23 base-installer: warning: /usr/lib/base-installer.d/20console-setup returned error code 127
Jul 12 17:30:55 base-installer: error: exiting on error base-installer/debootstrap-failed
Jul 12 17:30:55 main-menu[514]: WARNING **: Configuring 'bootstrap-base' failed with error code 1
Jul 12 17:30:55 main-menu[514]: WARNING **: Menu item 'bootstrap-base' failed.
Jul 12 17:30:56 main-menu[514]: INFO: Modifying debconf priority limit from 'high' to 'medium'
Jul 12 17:30:56 debconf: Setting debconf/priority to medium
Jul 12 17:30:57 main-menu[514]: DEBUG: resolver (libnewt0.52): package doesn't exist (ignored)
Jul 12 17:30:57 main-menu[514]: DEBUG: resolver (ext2-modules): package doesn't exist (ignored)
Jul 12 17:30:59 main-menu[514]: INFO: Menu item 'save-logs' selected
```

I first implemented a DHCP/TFTP solution using pxelinux (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer) but have since moved to gpxelinux with syslinux to try to get this to work (plus it appears that the use of HTTP is faster than TFTP etc.). Still with no success I attempted to use a simple Kickstart file:

```
install
url --url http://10.16.25.80:4040/ubuntu/repository/
```

...along with a complete **apt-mirror** repository (as suggested here -> [Unable to install 12.10 with PXE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204786/unable-to-install-12-10-with-pxe)) with no improvement. I also tried using the "ubuntu-12.04.2-alternate-amd64.iso" image as well.

#### Server Hardware (the one I'm attempting to reimage)

- Dell PowerEdge R320
- 4 physical hard drives configured as hardware RAID 0 with one 4TB virtual drive.
- 16GB RAM

## About The Host Server (server used to build)

The hosting server is of similar hardware and was previously configured with Ubuntu Server 12.04 (precise) with Chef server 10.18.2 using the web-ui which uses merb for web services (HTTP). This server acts as the DHCP/HTTP/TFTP/APT-MIRROR host.

### Installed DHCP

`sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server`

**/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server**

```
INTERFACES="eth0"
```

**/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**

```
ddns-update-style none;
option domain-name "corp.com";
option domain-name-servers dns1.corp.com, dns2.corp.com;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
log-facility local7;
subnet 10.16.25.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.16.25.195 10.16.25.199;
  option domain-name "corp.com";
  option domain-name-servers 10.10.10.200, 10.10.10.201;
  option routers 10.16.25.1;
  option broadcast-address 10.16.25.254;
  option ntp-servers 10.10.10.203;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
  filename "gpxelinux.0";
}
```

### Installed TFTP

`sudo apt-get install tftpd-hpa`

**/etc/default/tftpd-hpa**

```
RUN_DAEMON=”yes”
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
```

### Installed SysLinux

`sudo apt-get install syslinux`

**/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default**

```
...
LABEL Server (Preseed/HTTP)
    KERNEL http://10.16.25.80:4040/pxe/ubuntu/12.04/alternate-amd64/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
    APPEND auto=true interface=eth0 hostname=coolservername url=http://10.16.25.80:4040/pxe/preseed/coolservername.seed initrd=http://10.16.25.80:4040/pxe/ubuntu/12.04/alternate-amd64/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz --
```

### Configured A Preseed File

The seed file is located at `http://10.16.25.80:4040/pxe/preseed/coolservername.seed`

```
# Language:
d-i debian-installer/language string en
# Country:
d-i debian-installer/country string US
# Detect keyboard layout?
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
# Country of origin for the keyboard:
d-i keyboard-configuration/layout select English (US)
# Keyboard layout:
d-i keyboard-configuration/variant select English (US)
# Domain name:
d-i netcfg/get_domain string corp.com
# Disable that annoying WEP key dialog.
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string
# Configure the application repository mirror
d-i mirror/protocol string http
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string 10.16.25.80:4040
d-i mirror/http/directory string /pxe/ubuntu/repository/
#d-i mirror/http/directory string /pxe/ubuntu/12.04/server-amd64/
#d-i mirror/http/directory string /pxe/ubuntu/12.04/alternate-amd64/
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
d-i mirror/suite string precise
# Create a normal user account
d-i passwd/user-fullname string A really cool default user
d-i passwd/username string coolusername
# Normal user's encrypted password (using an MD5 hash)
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password 12345678901234567890123456789012
# Set to true to encrypt the first user's home directory
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
# Only ask the UTC question if there are other operating systems installed.
d-i clock-setup/utc-auto boolean true
# Controls whether or not the hardware clock is set to UTC
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
# Time zone setup
d-i time/zone string US/Pacific
# Configure disk storage and partitions
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
# If one of the disks that are going to be automatically partitioned
# contains an old LVM configuration, the user will normally receive a
# warning. This can be preseeded away...
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
# The same applies to pre-existing software RAID array:
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
# And the same goes for the confirmation to write the lvm partitions.
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
# For LVM partitioning, you can select how much of the volume group to use
# for logical volumes.
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
# You can choose one of the three predefined partitioning recipes:
# - atomic: all files in one partition
# - home:   separate /home partition
# - multi:  separate /home, /usr, /var, and /tmp partitions
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation, provided
# that you told it what to do using one of the methods above.
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
# By default the installer requires that repositories be authenticated
# using a known gpg key. This setting can be used to disable that
# authentication. Warning: Insecure, not recommended.
d-i debian-installer/allow_unauthenticated boolean true
# Package selection - run this grep (from existing) to see list of available options
# "grep Task /usr/share/tasksel/ubuntu-tasks.desc"
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect server, standard
# Individual additional packages to install
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server
# Whether to upgrade packages after debootstrap.
# Allowed values: none, safe-upgrade, full-upgrade
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select full-upgrade
# Policy for applying updates. May be "none" (no automatic updates),
# "unattended-upgrades" (install security updates automatically), or
# "landscape" (manage system with Landscape).
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select none
# By default, the system's locate database will be updated after the
# installer has finished installing most packages. This may take a while, so
# if you don't want it, you can set this to "false" to turn it off.
d-i pkgsel/updatedb boolean true
# Only install basic language packs. Let tasksel ask about tasks.
d-i pkgsel/language-pack-patterns string
# No language support packages.
d-i pkgsel/install-language-support boolean false
# Verbose output and no boot splash screen.
d-i debian-installer/quiet boolean false
d-i debian-installer/splash boolean false
# This is fairly safe to set, it makes grub install automatically to the MBR
# if no other operating system is detected on the machine.
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
# This one makes grub-installer install to the MBR if it also finds some other
# OS, which is less safe as it might not be able to boot that other OS.
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
# Wait for two seconds in grub
d-i grub-installer/timeout string 2
# This will prevent the installer from ejecting the CD during the reboot.
d-i cdrom-detect/eject boolean false
# Avoid that last message about the install being complete.
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
# Overwrite the server's network configuration file (/etc/network/interfaces)
d-i preseed/run string coolservername.sh
```

### Installed apt-mirror

`sudo apt-get install apt-mirror`

**/etc/apt/mirror.list**

```
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer universe universe/debian-installer multiverse multiverse/debian-installer
deb-amd64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer universe universe/debian-installer multiverse multiverse/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer universe universe/debian-installer multiverse multiverse/debian-installer
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

`http://10.16.25.80:4040/pxe/ubuntu/repository` is a symbolic link to the mirrored files at "/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/".

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated on getting past these errors and successfully helping the reimaging/rebuilding of this server as I've spent much time investigating and searching with no luck...

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you still can reproduce or still facing this problem?